# take nullable and return non-nullable reference and value types in single method

Tags: c#, .net-core, nullable, roslyn-code-analysis

i want a method that takes a nullable and returns nonnullable.  it can be value or ref type. i only seem to be able to do this by having2 methods:

```
    public static T Do<T>(
       T? t
    ) where T: struct
    {
        return t == null ? throw new Exception("") : t.Value;
    }

    public static T Do<T>(
       T? t
    ) where T : class
    {
        return t == null ? throw new Exception("") : t;
    }
```

is there a way to do this with a single method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, unfortunately you can't do this with a single method.

Because the `?` annotation on a value type `TValueType` is actually C# syntactic sugar for the .NET type `Nullable<TValueType>`. But for a reference type `TRefType`, the `?` annotation `TRefType?`does not change the annotated type, it's still just the type *TRefType*; with `?` here just being a metadata annotation for the static code analysis.

So, ignoring the static code analysis metadata, your code is equivalent to:

```
    public static T Do<T>(
       Nullable<T> t
    ) where T: struct
    {
        return t == null ? throw new Exception("") : t.Value;
    }

    public static T Do<T>(
       T t
    ) where T : class
    {
        return t == null ? throw new Exception("") : t;
    }
```

It should now be apparent that you can't have a single method with a signature where its parameter is both `Nullable<T>` and not `Nullable<T>` at the same time...

Well, you might think how about one method

```
public static T Do<T>(T? t)
{
    if (t is null) throw new Exception("");

    ... and now? How to distinguish between value and reference types?
}
```

but doing this would involve reflection both for identifying whether a given `T` is a value type or a reference type, and for dispatching the value to respective code/methods that either deal with value types or references types. While this would give you a single public method, the price is that your code would now become much more complicated and slower. Until a future C# version learns to pattern match whether a value is of a value type or a reference type, doing these kind of reflection shenanigans is seldomly worth the trouble in my opinion.

Comment: yeah even that proposed approach doesn't really work because T becomes Nullable<int> or int? which then means that method returns int? which is def not what i want.  Oh well....will mark as accepted as long as conflicting info comes in.